# ArcGIS error - "invalid SQL"

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, error, select-by-attribute

I have a map with a few different layers. One of these layers is a 'cities' layer. I am trying to use selection->select by attribute-> Select: "Pop_CL"=8 or 9 or 10..... where Pop_CL is the population class (ten being cities with the largest population). I keep on getting error messages though!

Error 1: There was an error executing the query. An invalid SQL statement was used. I am selecting each # from "get unique values." No idea why I keep getting an error!

Comment: please consult documentation: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000033000000

Answer (score 6):

With booleans, you need to repeat the query with the name of the field :

```
("Pop_CL"=8) or ("Pop_CL"=9) or ("Pop_CL"=10)
```

but in your case you could use

```
"Pop_CL" in (8,9,10)
```

Comment: Radouxju, you are fantastic. Worked like a charm. Thank you.